# jquery missing from rails v4 project

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using rails v4.2.4. I have tried creating a test app using the command

```
rails new app
```

The application.js file is referring to jquery, I have jquery-rails on my computer (gem which jquery-rails gives me the output), I have also ran bundle install.  However, I do not have jquery in my vendor/assets/javascripts directory and the only JS file in the app/assets/javascripts directory is the application.js file.  Even after copying the jquery files by hand in the vendor/assets directory, the web apge served by rails does not add the jquery file to the page.  Have I missed any steps in making sure that jquery is served by the rails project?

**application.js:**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

**application.html.erb**

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Testapp</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-tra
ck' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Can you post your app/assets/javascripts/application.js?

Comment: Can you also post the HTML output of your page?

Comment: I have a delete call on the page which does not work since there is no JS.  The HTML page has missing JS referenecces

Comment: Post the HTML please, that could be for a number of reasons

Comment: Keeping in mind that this is rails v4.2.4 which was released over two weeks ago, I have to wonder if that's the problem

Comment: Its not, I started a new app last week on Rails v4.2.4 and I'm using jQuery just fine

Comment: Also make sure you have <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %> in your application layout.

Comment: Also having both the jquery-rails gem install and the jquery source code manually added into the assets will cause a conflict. You'll be loading jquery twice.

Comment: updating with application layout file

Comment: What happens if you remove turbolinks from application.html.erb and application.js?

Comment: what do you think is the issue?

Comment: That turbolinks may be getting in the way - modifying three lines of code takes no time - so its a simple thing to try.

Comment: removing that means there is no reference what so ever to any JS

Comment: Is your CSS loading?